# Difference between Maven source plugin jar and jar-no-fork goal?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin

Could you give me a detail explanation about the difference between jar and jar-no-fork goal?

I see it from official site, but I can not get a clear idea for this.

Comment: One forks a thread, one doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean fork a thread?

Comment: The jar goal causes a warning in Jenkins, see https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-27372?focusedCommentId=231164&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-231164

Answer (score 60, accepted):

My interpretation: the `jar` goal is meant to be run from the command line (`mvn source:jar`), the `jar-no-fork` is meant to be bound to the lifecycle.

If you look at the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) for the `jar` goal the key phrase is "Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-sources prior to executing itself."  If you configure your POM to run the `source:jar` goal as part of the lifecycle, Maven will **re-run** all of the goals bound to `generate-sources` and its predecessors.  If you have many plugin goals bound to the validate or initialize phases all of those will run twice, lengthening the time of your build.

In contrast, `jar-no-fork` is what you attach to the build lifecycle because it expects to be bound to a phase somewhere after `generate-sources` and will not run the bound goals again.

I have verified this behavior by running Maven 3 with `-X` and reviewing the plugin executions that run.

Comment: The default phase and the minimum version are both described in the attributes section of the [jar-no-fork](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html) documentation.

Comment: This is my understanding as well, but then the strange thing is that the super POM of Maven 3.0.4 uses the jar goal, not the jar-no-fork goal in the release-profile. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps the jar-no-fork goal was added to the plugin after Maven 3.0.4 was released.  You'd have to check the release notes for both.