# How to create jar archive of projects sources with maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-source-plugin

I include the following snippet in a projects object model

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
  </plugin>
```

according to  [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html) the plugin attaches the jar goal to the package phase.
However doing "mvn clean ; mvn package" does not generate a project-sources.jar in the target directory.

EDIT: Propably i do not understand the comment from the website, which i quoted: "[The source:jar goal] Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package." I expected that, when i include the plugin section as shown above maven already binds the source:jar goal to the package phase. Am i mistaking here? What does the comment mean?

matthias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading.  The plugin has a default execution phase of package but there is no default goal. I believe that you have specify a goal in order for the plugin to work.

Comment: This answer is indeed "correct" and answers the "why" question that @Matthias directly asked (I upvoted), but for my money/Google search, both Raghuram and MichalKalinowski gave great examples to answer the inevitable "how".

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) to a maven life-cycle goal for it to generate the source jar.  Otherwise, you need to invoke it explicitly `mvn source:jar`.

As documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html), you can bind it to the `jar` goal.

Comment: Propably i do not understand the comment from the website, which i quoted: "[The source:jar goal] Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package." I expected the goal to be bound already (just be including the plugin definition).

Comment: @Matthias. Guess the document is incorrect.  You can run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see how other plugins (like `compile` get bound to a phase) but not this.  Also, the examples clearly indicate the need to bind the plugin to a phase.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

It uses then the default binding of `jar-no-fork` goal to `package` phase of the lifecycle and that's probably what you need here.

Comment: Please reread my question as i have tried to clarify my central point more clearly. I do not look for a working solution but for understanding the documenation that i quoted.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10568004/944849) for help understanding the docs.